# Is Apps Script JSON.parse() incorrectly stripping leading zeros from string object names?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have an Apps Script Web App which fetches JSON data.  I have run into problems where keys with leading zeros are modified (e.g "0123" becomes "123") when I call JSON.parse().  It seems to me like the function is treating my string as an integer but still returning it as a string. Is this the expected behavior?

This should reproduce my problem:

```
function jsontest() {
  var json = '{"0123":"foo", "bar":"0123", "foobar":123}';
  var test = JSON.parse(json);
  var check = ("0123" in test);
  var check2 = ("123" in test);

  Logger.log(test);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(test));
  Logger.log(check);
  Logger.log(check2);
}
```

It produces this in the log:

```
[17-06-07 15:22:56:241 CDT] {123=foo, bar=0123, foobar=123}
[17-06-07 15:22:56:241 CDT] {"123":"foo","bar":"0123","foobar":123}
[17-06-07 15:22:56:242 CDT] false
[17-06-07 15:22:56:243 CDT] true
```

Comment: Your code definitely does not do that in a browser console or in Node. Where does that "Logger" facility come from?

Comment: The Google Apps Script interface.

Comment: Well maybe it's an artifact of the logging. Maybe explicitly check for `"0123" in test` as an expression (and it should be `true`). Object property names are always strings, so something stripping leading zeros is a bug.

Comment: `("0123" in test)` is false.  `("123" in test)` is true.

Comment: OK well are you *sure* that your source JSON has that leading zero? That really cannot happen if your JSON looks like what's in the question.

Comment: Yes, some of the data indeed has the leading zero.  I am not sure what you are after as it seems to me like the code example demonstrates the problem without bringing my data into question.

Comment: Well the code example does *not* demonstrate the problem in any environment I've tried.

Comment: After testing your code in Google's Apps Script editor its clear that you sir have found a bug. Google Apps Script is a custom implementation of ES5 and bugs have been known to crop up every now and then. I think problem lies with the JSON.parse method

Please report it via Google's issue tracker and reference this stackoverflow thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Apps Script, `JSON.parse()` removes single and double quotations. At this time, if the numbers are included in the keys, the keys are changed to number. So "0123" of key is changed to a number "123". As a method for avoiding this, you can use `eval()`. By using `eval()`, single and double quotations are removed without converting string to number.

I don't know whether this is best method. So please see this as just one proposal.

**Sample :**

```
var json = '{"0123":"foo", "bar":"0123", "foobar":123}';

var test1 = JSON.parse(json);
var test2 = eval("json=" + json);

Logger.log("%s, %s", test1, JSON.stringify(test1));
Logger.log("%s, %s", test2, JSON.stringify(test2));
```

**Result :**

```
{123=foo, bar=0123, foobar=123}, {"123":"foo","bar":"0123","foobar":123}
{bar=0123, foobar=123.0, 0123=foo}, {"0123":"foo","bar":"0123","foobar":123}
```

When above sample is used for your script, the modified script is as follows.

**Modified script :**

```
function jsontest() {
  var json = '{"0123":"foo", "bar":"0123", "foobar":123}';

  var test = eval("json=" + json); // <-- Added
//  var test = JSON.parse(json);

  var check = ("0123" in test);
  var check2 = ("123" in test);

  Logger.log(test);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(test));
  Logger.log(check);
  Logger.log(check2);
}
```

**Result :**

```
{bar=0123, foobar=123.0, 0123=foo}
{"0123":"foo","bar":"0123","foobar":123}
true
false
```

Comment: There is something definitely wrong with Apps Script's implementation. If you take the jsontest function and paste it into Google Chrome's Dev tool's console window (taking care to replace each Logger.log with console.log), upon execution you'll get the expected results without the need for an eval. Good workaround though using eval.

Comment: @Dimu Designs Thank you for your comments. Yes. I know it. So I thought that this is one of solutions for GAS. But since my answer was not enough, I updated it. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a good solution.  I have submitted the bug to Google's issue tracker; hopefully they will implement a permanent fix.